# Intellij Error - Use of Internal Package is not allowed in golang parent directory

Tags: go, intellij-idea

[image]

I am importing a project that works on other machines but not mine. The top level cmd/main.go is importing a package from the ./internal directory which is allowed by Go of course. The GoROOT is set, Go modules integration is enabled, go mod vendor; go mod tidy command successfully completes, and no other errors are reported by the IDE. This is part of an empty project that was created, and this particular directory with the error is a new module from existing sources. Any ideas are welcome after 2 days of trying to resolve this issue, thank you.

I have a new M1 MacBook Pro, and encountered the issue originally on the latest IntelliJ 2022.1 (Both Intel & Apple Silicon Version) so I downgraded to an older version 2020.3.4 (Apple Silicon Version) and still have this issue

Go Version: go1.18 darwin/arm64

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of your project (with `/cmd/main.go` and `/internal/package.go` files).

Comment: I actually can't reproduce the issue when starting a new empty project. I used the same structure with an internal directory at the top level and was able to import into cmd/main.go just fine. In the project with the problem, we have a module declared as xyz.company/fps/component, and when xyz.company/fps was removed the internal package can be imported properly (after running go mod vendor). Importing internal packages from a file inside the internal directory also does not work.